# HandlerInterceptorAdapter.postHandle doesn't get called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to populate all pages with variables, but it wont work:

```
public class PagePopulationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public void postHandle(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("hello", "world");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public @Override void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new PagePopulationInterceptor());
    }
}
```

When putting `${hello}` on a page it's just empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your `postHandle()` method has incorrect signature, therefore it doesn't override the actual method of `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`. The correct one is:

```
public void postHandle(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
    Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) { ... }
```

You can prevent this kind of problems by annotating methods that are intended to override superclass methods by `@Override`:

```
@Override
public void postHandle(ModelMap map) { ... }
```

In this case compiler will give you error because this method doesn't override anything.